# Realsense Viewer / SDK does not open

Tags: windows, camera, sdk, intel, realsense

I bought a Intel NUC Hades Canyon VR NUC8i7HVK PC and added an 8gb Kingston ValueRAM and 120GB Kingston UV500 SSD, running Windows 10, together with an Intel Realsense Depth Camera
I have tried to install the Realsense SDK, Realsense Viewer and Realsense Depth Quality tool aren't working.
They literally don't open without any error messages.
I have reinstalled it numerous times.
I'm intending to use it with the Nuitrack library and Unity for Skeleton tracking and have successfully done so with my regular computer.
However, now nothing seems to work anymore.
I have no idea how to go about it, since I don't know where to look. Any ideas?